# Packages I installed using virtualenv are not installed in virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv

I want to use the virtualenv package while developing this project.

I activate my virtual environment with `venv\Script\Active`. Everything is ok so far, but when installing a package while my virtual environment is active, the installed package is not installed in venv, but directly in Python on my computer.

Comment: Rather than directly using `pip`, try installing like `python -m pip install requests`

Comment: There's no reason to use virtualenv for this. `venv` module is built into python and offers the same feature of dependency management

Comment: As OneCicketeer said. Not to mention that many modern build systems (poetry, pipenv, hatch, etc...) provide rich environment management as well

Answer (score 0):

You most likely used your global `pip` to install the package, which does not know about your virtual environment. (Just like you can use other global commands like `ls` inside your shell that opened the virtual environment, you can use the global python)

To avoid mishaps like this, run all python-modules with the python-interpreter of your virtual-environment using the `-m`-syntax for executing modules.

```
(venv)$> python -m pip install whatever
```

because if the python-interpreter is the correct one, pip will be correct too.

Comment: Hi, i tried what you said. But its not working. I have still same problem. :/

Comment: @AnılÇelik  in that case, please show the exact commands (including output) for your attempt to install the packages and run code that's using them.